# convert to ABSOLUTE in logback

Tags: log4j, slf4j, logback

I used layout in log4j %d{ABSOLUTE}.
now I am moving to logback but I do not find this option.
what is the corresponded pattern in logback?

Answer (score 2):

Log4j's %d{ABSOLUTE} just uses the AbsoluteTimeDateFormat[1], which formats a date as "HH:mm:ss,SSS". The corresponding layout pattern would thus be:

```
 %d{"HH:mm:ss,SSS"}
```

[1] http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/helpers/AbsoluteTimeDateFormat.html